# property return sevral value

Tags: vb.net, oop, readonly

I want to get several value from a read only property.in Below is my code

```
Public Class Class1
            ReadOnly Property Ca As New Class2
End Class





Public Class Class2

        ReadOnly Property getass(q As Integer, ww As String) As Integer
            Get
                Codes that return q And ww

            End Get

        End Property
End Class


Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim a As New Class1
        Dim ret As Integer
        Dim qq As Integer = Nothing
        Dim qqq As String = Nothing
        ret = a.Ca.getass(qq, qqq)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want finally get qq=q and qqq=ww...
thanks

Comment: "I want" is not a question and does not tell us if you are getting an error, what the error is and where it is.  Please read [Ask] carefully and also take the [Tour]

Comment: how to get from readonly property several value like above code

Comment: in really i want by ret=a.ca.getass(qq,qqq) get the qq and qqq that qq in the ID of Student and qqq is student last name.if the qq and qqq get to database and return value the ret=0 else ret =1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a Property for this purpose.

Instead just declare a Sub that modifies the passed parameters like this:

```
Public Class Class2
    Sub getass(ByRef q As Integer, ByRef ww As String)
        Dim _q as Integer
        Dim _w as String

        'do whatever you want 
        'then assign the final values and end sub
        q = _q
        ww = _ww
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then use the sub like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim a As New Class1
        Dim qq As Integer = Nothing
        Dim qqq As String = Nothing
        a.Ca.getass(qq, qqq)
        'At this point your local qq and qqq will have the value setted by the getass Sub
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please consider that this is not a good design pattern for your final intent of having a student ID and Name.

Consider creating a Class "Student" with all the properties you want and make Class2 (I can suppose is a classroom or something like that) return a "Student" object.

Or you could use a [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) structure

EDIT:
If you still want to do this through an interface try this:

```
Public Class Class2
    Public ReadOnly Property getass(ByRef q As Integer, ByRef ww As String) as Integer
      Get
        Dim _q as Integer
        Dim _w as String

        'do whatever you want 
        'then assign the final values and end sub
        q = _q
        ww = _ww

        return ID 'ID is what you want (Integer)
      End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: thank you very much...if i want ret return a value like 0 that shows the code can access to database and returned values what can i do?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your english

Comment: yes you are right.My English is weak.I want  ret (ret = a.Ca.getass(qq, qqq)) the my above code return 0 if run was successful.

Comment: @MDA If you want to return and integer, make the method a Function (`Private Function getass(ByRef q As Integer, ByRef ww As String) As Integer`) instead of a Sub and you can return an integer with the `Return` statement.